# Pass/fail test of xml- parsing

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-parsing

So i have this code parsing xml files. What I need it to do is check for values that are within the range and write out if it pass/fail. I'm not sure if my code: "where" statements are correct. I need the code to look for the "Max" and "Min" of each statement and to write out for example XMax the value is less than 287 it passed and greater than failed.

```
   string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {

            var query = from file in fileEntries
                        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
                        let x = doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib").Single()
                        where (int)x.Attribute("Max") > 287
                        where (int)x.Attribute("Min") < -50 
                        let y = doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib").Single()
                        where (int)y.Attribute("Max") > 645
                        where (int)y.Attribute("Min") > -87
                        let z = doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib").Single()
                        where (int)z.Attribute("Max") > 20
                        where (int)z.Attribute("Min") > -130
                        select new 
                       {

                            XMax = x.Element("Max").Value,
                            XMin = x.Element("Min").Value,
                            YMax = y.Element("Max").Value,
                            YMin = y.Element("Min").Value,
                            ZMax = z.Element("Max").Value,
                            ZMin = z.Element("Min").Value
                        };
```

Here is an example of what one xml file looks like:

```
<XAxisCalib>
      <Max>281.68</Max>
      <Min>-46.79</Min>
    </XAxisCalib>
    <YAxisCalib>
      <Max>570.57</Max>
      <Min>-123.24</Min>
    </YAxisCalib>
    <ZAxisCalib>
      <Max>31.01</Max>
      <Min>-100.95</Min>
```

Comment: do you want it to write out Pass or Fail for each node, or for the object as a whole?

Comment: For each node to determine pass fail.

Answer (score 0):

Well your approach appear a little weak to me, because user can potentially mistakes and write rubbish instead of an int, so your where will fail. Isn't better to use a pure xsd approach and then validate the single entities ? As a personal experience, having an XSD to validat ethe simple xml, and a validation per entity lead to a easy to mantain and extend code, even if the inpuit is machine generated ( since sometimes specification changes ;) ) so I would prefer the old fashon way instead of linq to XML to solve such kind of situation, but is just my opinion coming from my experience.

Comment: the xml file is created from a machine build so it will always be a int number value. My code could be completely wrong that may be the case thats why I'm here seeking help of the best way to write this code.

Comment: @Casey the best way, in order to me is to have an XSD to validate the shape, then have an entity based valiodation, you achieve an easyer to extend and mantain code.